# Username correct, password incorrect?

Tags: php, sql, authentication

In a login system, how can you tell if the user has entered the password incorrectly? Do you perform two SQL queries, one to find the username, and then one to find the username and matching (salted+hashed etc) password? I'm asking this because If the user entered the password incorrectly, I want to update the failed_login_attempts column I have.

If you perform two queries wouldn't that increase overhead?

If you did a query like this, how would you tell if the password entered was correct or not, or whether the username doesn't exist:

```
 SELECT * FROM author 
 WHERE username = '$username'
 AND password = '$password'
 LIMIT 1
```

( ^ NB: I'm keeping it simple, will use hash and salt, and will sanitize input in real one.)

Something like this:

```
$user = perform_Query() // get username and password?

 if ($user['username'] == $username && $user['password'] == $password)
 {
     return $user;
 }
 elseif($user['username'] == $username && $user['password'] !== $password)
 {   // here the password doesn't match
     // update failed_login_attemps += 1
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overthinking it. Only one query is required:

```
SELECT * FROM author WHERE username = '$username';
```

Then do:

```
if ($user['password'] == saltedHash($password,$user['salt'])) {
    return "successful";
}
else {
    return "failed";
}
```

Username must be unique. Otherwise this won't work. I would advise against making username non-unique because it causes a lot of other headaches apart from this.

Comment: or `SELECT username,password FROM ... ` +1 though

Comment: @Robert: or `SELECT username,password,salt ...`. That reminds me, there's a bug in my example code... fixed.

Answer (score 3):

> If you perform two queries wouldn't that increase overhead?

I'd say it doesn't matter really. Many complex web frameworks issue dozens or hundreds of queries per request. One more or less won't change things much.

I think it's really up to preference. Fetching the whole user row, and then checking the password on PHP side makes the most sense as far as I can see, because you then already have the ID you need to update the `failed_logins` column.

Comment: I'd add that single update would be 1000 times more expensive than 10 additional selects

Comment: +1 as i personally think people are a little over concious of running several queries.

Comment: @Robert yeah. I've seen plugin-laden Drupal sites with 600-700 queries *per request*. One more or less looks really unimportant in comparison!

Comment: yea people who build there own sites run like 10~20 queries and worry about 1 more per request :/

Answer (score 0):

What we do is perform one query to find the user (based on userid) and we select the UserId, PwSalt, and PwHash.

If no user is found then we know it is an invalid username.

If the user is found, we hash the password and compare it to the pwHash from the query. If the hash doesn't match we update the failed login attempts.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, $user will be empty if username or password is incorrect

```
SELECT password = '$password' AS is_legit, * 
FROM author 
WHERE username = '$username'
LIMIT 1

$user = perform_Query() // get username and password?
// $user will be empty if the username is incorrect
$user_exists = $user.length > 0;
// to make sure we don't address a 
// non-existent array element
if($user_exists && $user['password'] == $password){ 
     return $user;
}
elseif($user_exists && $user['password'] !== $password)
{   // here the password doesn't match, but the user does
    // update failed_login_attemps += 1
    // be sure to let the user know that the penetration
    // attempt is halfway complete
}
else{
    // F4il
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The way (*and many others*) create login systems is like so:

- On Registration

  - create a unique hash and store along with username,password
- On Login

  - Pull username,password,hash from database
  - Use the clause `WHERE username = '$username'`
  - If theres 1 row, the username is correct
  - build a compiled hash with `hash($post_pass,$user_hash)` and compare with $user_pass

Also if you return anything at 1 point of your method anything after would not be run, so

```
if ($user['username'] == $username && $user['password'] == $password)
 {
     return $user;
 }
 elseif($user['username'] == $username && $user['password'] !== $password)
 {   // here the password doesn't match
     // update failed_login_attemps += 1
 }
```

can be modified to

```
if ($user['username'] == $username && $user['password'] == $password)
{
    return $user;
}
return false
```

because if (`$user['username'] == $username && $user['password'] == $password`) is met, then the return would be executed there for the false would not be executed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Col, in what context, in general storing the hash would mean that the hash is unique per person. creating less chance of a collision by password crackers.

Comment: What collision you are talking about? Am i got you correct, you do store this hash **along** with password?

Comment: Theres a username, password (encrypted), hash which is salted with the raw password. and collision such as md5 collisions. http://www.mscs.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/

Comment: yes you have me correct we store the password in the database, and there is still a security risk but its still safer then using a site wide hash that never changes. http://elbertf.com/2010/01/store-passwords-safely-with-php-and-mysql/

Comment: It seems you're stuffed with some "wise advises"  but understand not a bit of it. And you repeat it mechanically, without any relation to the actual question and common sense

Comment: I understand the answers I provide pretty well, maybe I fail in repeating them in a understandable form, We all work differently, our minds process information in complex ways and maybe I have a flaw in the area of repeating things which i understand differently to many others, My apologise for posting my answer and it not coming across as a helpful as i tried to be.

Comment: But you didn't repeat not even answered once one very simple question, "What's the use of such a hash if you have plain text password as well".

Comment: From the fourth comment above, I say: *There's a username, password (**encrypted**), hash which is salted with the raw password* and where was it stated: **What's the use of such a hash if you have plain text password as well**

Comment: No, it just describing the data structure. But how does it work? What's the benefit of comparing that hash over comparing just username and password?

Comment: Well the simplest is that IF the database got leaked the users passwords would be visible, and along with email addresses the user can be taken for a ride if there using the same password, paypal,email,visa etc. storing the passwords encrypted would help prevent this.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But your answer is something different, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, its different because the OP does not require help with security, but the actual query construction, I have described login system as a whole but focused on the login query